# Qual é a forma mais correta para denominar um "paper" em português?

Tags: português-europeu, termos-em-inglês, termos

Cientistas ou investigadores publicam (o que as pessoas que falam inglês referem-se a) *papers*.

Qual é o termo mais adequado para referir-se a estas publicações ou *papers* em português (possivelmente português de Portugal, mas são também bem vindas as outras variantes)?

Answer (score 6):

Dependendo de onde esse "paper" vai ser apresentado ou publicado, aqui no Brasil ele pode ser chamado de:

- **trabalho** - Pode ser um estudo feito por estudantes universitários, por pós-graduandos, ou profissionais de qualquer área.  **Um trabalho** pode ser publicado em uma revista da especialidade, pode ser apresentado em um congresso, ou como conclusão de um curso de pós-graduação. Pode também fazer parte do currículo de um determinado curso.

  ex:

> - "Escrevi um trabalho sobre a eficácia da Claritromicina nas infecções por germes gram-negativos"
> - "Mais de mil e quinhentos trabalhos foram inscritos para apresentação no último Congresso Brasileiro de Cardiologia"
> - "A professora de história quer que façamos um trabalho sobre Os Grandes Navegadores"

- **artigo** - Um trabalho publicado em uma revista pode também ser chamado de artigo. "Você leu aquele artigo sobre..."
- Um trabalho mais elaborado, seguindo um protocolo bem desenhado, com extensa lista de referências biblioráficas já pode ser chamado de **monografia**, que tem seu correspondente em Inglês, assim como outras denominações como **"tese"**, **"estudo"** e **"pesquisa"**.

Comment: +1, mas queria sugerir algumas edições: `paper` em inglês não precisa ser apresentado ou publicado, pode ser só um trabalho de casa pedido pelo professor numa faculdade; uma única `pesquisa` ou `estudo` costuma gerar vários `papers`; e todas as universidades para as quais eu estudei/trabalhei eram muito mesquinhas com os termos `tese` e `monografia`, termos estritamente dedicados aos trabalhos de conclusão do doutorado e da graduação, respectivamente.

Comment: @RamonMelo   No UMMC onde estudei, também o termo era paper para qualquer coisa.  Note bem que minhas observações se referem a às diversas formas de traduzir paper para o português e o significado de cada uma das traduções.  TRABALHO =   "feito por estudantes universitários, por graduados, por profissionais"     "pode ser publicado" (ou não, está implícito)    "fazer parte do currículo de um determinado curso"  (até mesmo curso primário ou secundário), pode (ou não) ser apresentado em congressos.

Comment: E o que disse eu que chamamos de monografia?   Um paper com um protocolo bem desenhado, seguindo as normas da ABNT e com uma lista extensa de referências bibliográficas. Eles chamam de paper e ocasionalmente de monografia.

Comment: Eu concordo, e acredito que ficou mais claro no comentário do que na resposta.

Comment: Em Portugal o mais comum seria artigo, ou [artigo cientifico](http://docentes.ismt.pt/~m_pocinho/elaboracao_do_artigo_cientifico.pdf).

Comment: É trabalho mesmo. As vezes também virá artigo. Pesquisa etc. é outra coisa. Acho uma barbaridade dizer paper em português. Credo. A paper can be published or unpublished. For college (university), it is still um trabalho, regardless. A paper can be published in a journal, it which case, the paper is an article in a journal. Artigo. Claro.To write a paper for a class is fazer um trabalho para um curso qualquer.

Comment: @Lambie não entendi, segundo o que dizes, então um paper seria um trabalho?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, paper é um trabalho [formal e escrito]. Mas nem todo paper é publicado.E só isso que estou dizendo...."Fiz um trabalho de 25 páginas." I wrote a 25-page paper.

Comment: @Lambie não acho nada que seja. Seja publicado ou não, eu quando faço um trabalho formatado em modo "artigo cientifico" chamo-lhe um artigo seja publicado ou não.

Comment: @JorgeB the term paper and article are not synonymous 100%. That is all I am saying.